# Integrate C++ Basler camera libraries in Matlab on Mac

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

How do I integrate C++ libraries into Matlab 2018b (macOS Mojave) to use them with the `mex()` function. Currently I want to use the C++ library of a Basler camera to address it with mex. For this I have to include the following files:

> *.framework, Header Files, *.dylib Files

Otherwise the `#include` call in the c++ file wont work. I have integrated the libraries without problems in QT Creator with the following commands and the `#include <pylon/...>` works fine:

> mac: LIBS += -F$$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/ -framework
>   pylon macx: LIBS +=
>   -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/
>   -lLog_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1 macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/
>   -lGenApi_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam
>   DEPENDPATH +=
>   $$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam
>   INCLUDEPATH +=
>   $$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries
>   DEPENDPATH +=
>   $$PWD/../../../../../../Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries
>   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -F/Library/Frameworks

In Matlab I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work and there is an error when calling the library in the c++ file:

```matlab
ipath_1 = '-I/Library/Frameworks';
ipath_2 = '-I/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Headers/GenICam';
ipath_3 = '-I/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries';
lib_1 = '-L/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ -lLog_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1';
lib_2 = '-L/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ -lGCBase_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1';
lib_3 = '-L/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ -lGenApi_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1';
mex('-largeArrayDims',...
    '-c',...
     ipath_1, ipath_2, ipath_3,...
     lib_1, lib_2, lib_3,...
    'basler_set_get.cpp')
% Error:
% #include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
%          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% 1 error generated.
```

How can I manage the integration in Matlab ? I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Where is `pylon/PylonIncludes.h` in your file system? The compiler is telling you, what the issue is.

Comment: The Headers are in `/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers` Linking the headers with '-I..' to mex leads also to the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encounters the same problem, I would like to post a solution that I have found out in the meantime. If the mex call is executed with these flags, then everything is compiled correctly:

```matlab
mex  '-I/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/GenICam'...
    '-I/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers/pylon/usb'...
    '-I/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Headers'...
    '-L/Library/Frameworks/pylon.framework/Versions/A/Libraries'...
    '-lGCBase_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1.dylib'...
    '-lGenApi_gcc_v3_1_Basler_pylon_v5_1.dylib'...
    CXXFLAGS='-F/Library/Frameworks $CXXFLAGS'...
    LDFLAGS='-framework pylon $LDFLAGS'...
    LIBS+='-framework pylon'...
    [YOUR FILENAME].cpp
```